# zClip freezes Firefox up

Tags: flash, firefox, freeze, zclip

Used this plugin for a long time, but recently it started badly freezing up my Firefox. Works fine in Chrome and even IE (!).

Is it a Firefox bug associated with some sort of incompatibility with Flash? I am using the most recent versions of Firefox and Flash Player as of this moment:

- Firefox: 18.0.2
- Flash Player: 11.5.502.149

To test, just click the "Copy" button on their website:
http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

To unfreeze - right button click the browser tab (also weird).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [regression in Firefox 18](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=829557) which should be fixed in Firefox 20.
It shouldn't happen with newer ZeroClipboard versions though (see [comment 12](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=829557#c12)), so upgrading it might be a work-around.

Comment: Don't you mean newer "Firefox" versions? It isn't fixed in 19, but may be in 20.

Comment: @Lonnie: I actually meant newer zCb versions, see [comment 12](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=829557#c12). 20 may be getting unlikely as we're already into the beta for a bit and the fix hasn't landed yet.

Comment: hi, where can i get the latest version ? Searched in google not able to get the file. Is there any location we can know ?

Comment: @sandy: You can get the most recent ZeroClipboard release [here](http://zeroclipboard.github.io/ZeroClipboard/). Note though that this is issue does not happen with the current Firefox releases, only Fx 18 and 19 were affected.

Comment: @georg fritzsche : Thanks for that. Yes, thats correct. You know what, firefox 19 in linux machine works fine !!!. The issues in fx 18 19 are only in windows machine i guess.....